# Looping and processing two REST API calls sequentially in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have a list of items called projects with two folder ids. I want to loop through the list of projects, call an endpoint to get the tasks in folder 1, then call an endpoint to get the tasks in folder 2, and then merge the result. I'm having trouble making this code run in the sequential manner I'm describing above. I've tried Promises and Aysnc/Await and I can't get anything working. Here's my current code:

```
function processAllTasks() {
  var emptyPromise = Promise.resolve();

  for(const Project of filteredProjects){
  emptyPromise = emptyPromise.then(function() {
    return getTasksForProjectFolderID(Project.FolderID1);
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    array1 = result;
    getTasksForProjectFolderID(Project.FolderID2).then(function(result2) {
      console.log(result2);
      array2 = result2;
   })
  });
}
}
```

Where Array1 and Array2 are the two arrays I want to later merge and process. They are defined in the global scope. My rest function getTasksForProjectFolderID looks like as follows:

```
function getTasksForProjectFolderID(projectFolderID) {
  return rp({
    url: url + projectFolderID + '/tasks',
    headers: headers
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response;
  });
}
```

Where rp is `const rp = require('request-promise');`

Comment: Have you made sure that `getTasksForProjectFolderID()` is working correctly with a single call?

Comment: @TaylorKrusen Yep, I tried it separately before attempting to loop it

Comment: What is not working in your current ?

Comment: @TaylorKrusen Yep, it contains an array of objects containing both ID's

Comment: @Weedoze The code just rolls through the loop and logs 'undefined' for each one

Comment: Can you please post an example of what the payload you get back in the response from the endpoint?

Comment: @MattTheHack Please try to log the **response** inside the **then** in your **getTasksForProjectFolderID()** function

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, avoid defining variables in the global scope where possible. If you need an object that has the results of both queries, then that is what your function should return.

You don't need promises in your loop to solve this. Your `getTasksForProjectFolderID()` is already handling the asynchronous call to fetch your data.

I would do something like this (this depends on how you want to structure your return data):

```
function processAllTasks(filteredProjects) {
  let results = {};

  for (const projectID of filteredProjects) {
    const taskList = getTasksForProjectFolderId(projectID)
    results['Project.FolderID'] = taskList
  }
  return results;
}
```

Now your results object looks like this

```
{
  <First folder ID> : <Results of first query>,
  <Second folder ID> : <Results of second query>,
  etc...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unclear on how this works? Is order guaranteed here? I'm assuming the object looks like this:

{
  <First folder ID> : <Results of first query>,
  <Second folder ID> : <Results of second query>,
   <First folder ID> : <Results of third query>,
  <Second folder ID> : <Results of fourth query>,
etc...
}

Comment: It's an object which uses JSON notation. Objects do not have an implicit order like an array does.    
If you need help on how to combine the data from the responses you're getting back, then you need to update the question with more information. Specifically, what the payloads look like when you get them back and what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: It's a pretty fundamental JavaScript technique that uses dictionaries to store unique key value pairs in a way thats easy to reference. Basically, having a unique   key (in this case, your Folder ID), allows you to reference a specific value (in this case, the result of that Folder IDs query). Here's a decent writeup: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/JavaScript-Basics-How-to-create-a-Dictionary-with-KeyValue-pairs